# style new (modern) sites SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

How do i style modern style which comes with SharePoint 2013?

I couldn't find ribbon to add script editor/content editor.

I used to add CSS, JavaScript etc to modify, remove the navigation bar etc.

I want to remove the white spaces on the left and right and make the page more like the community site
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are BROWSE and PAGE ribbons in the classic team site UI as below.

As a team site admin, If we would like to edit the homepage of the team site, we can click PAGE > Edit.

[image]

If you are in the modern team site, please click **Return to classic team site** at the bottom left corner.

About the issue “365 Team Site Home Page missing edit ribbon”, could you share with us a screenshot? The snapshot you mentioned doesn’t display. Could you upload it again?

**Otherwise Check This Method.**

[image]

Comment: I am not able to switch back to classic Team site for some reason and I couldn't post a screen shot. the bottom left corner there is no  Return to classic team site

Comment: When I create a page by add a page option it always comes up as modern site.